# boto throwing an Content-MD5 error sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, subprocess, boto

So I basically wrote a function to upload a file to S3 using the key.set_contents_from_file() function but I'm finding it sometimes throws this error

```
<Error>
<Code>BadDigest</Code>
<Message>The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.</Message>    
<ExpectedDigest>TPCms2v7Hu43d+yoJHbBIw==</ExpectedDigest>
<CalculatedDigest>QSdeCsURt0oOlL3NxxGwbA==</CalculatedDigest>
<RequestId>2F0D40F29AA6DC94</RequestId><HostId>k0AC6vaV+Ip8K6kD0F4fkbdS13UdxoJ3X1M76zFUR/ZQgnIxlGJrAJ8BeQlKQ4m6</HostId></Error>
```

The function:

```
def uploadToS3(filepath, keyPath, version):
    bucket = connectToS3() # Simple gets my bucket and returns it

    key = Key(bucket)
    f = open(filepath,'r')

    key.name = keyPath
    key.set_metadata('version', version)
    key.set_contents_from_file(f)    # offending line
    key.make_public()
    key.close()
```

If I open a python shell and manually call it, it works without a hitch, however the way I have to handle it (in which it doesn't work) involves calling it from a subprocess. This is because the caller is a python3 script, 2to3 didn't work and I didn't want to deal with the various years old branches for python3 versions.

Anyway, that seems to actually run it correctly as it gets in the function, the inputs are what's expected (I had them print out), but the # offending line keeps throwing this error. I have no idea what the cause is.

Is it possible bucket isn't being set properly? I feel like if that were the case calling Key(bucket) would have thrown an error

So I essentially run the below script, once as a subprocess called from a python3 script, the other from the console

```
sudo -u www-data python botoUtilities.py uploadToS3 /path/to/file /key/path
```

I have this logic inside to pass it to the correct function

```
func=None
args=[]

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if not func:
        g = globals()
        func = g[arg]
    else:
        if arg=='True':
            args.append(True)
        elif arg=='False':
            args.append(False)
        else:
            args.append(arg)

if func:
    wrapper(func, args)
```

It runs in both cases (I write to a file to print out the args) but only in the console case does it not get the error. This is incredibly frustrating. I can't figure out what is done differently. All I know is that it's not possible to send data to S3 using boto run from a subprocess

Comment: Could you be uploading a file that's still being written... or somehow hasn't been closed or fully flushed?  I would try decoding the values they are saying they calculated, and compare to the actual file, to see if you are calculating incorrectly or they are getting a corrupt upload.  Seems like it has to be one or the other... doesn't sound like it could be a config issue.

Comment: I thought that might be the case but I get the same error even when I try set_contents_from_string. It really does seem like the main issue is when I call it in a subprocess. For some reason any content I try to send to S3 fails.

Comment: So just to add a bit more, I manually compute it and get the same value that the error says it expects. For some reason the one that is computed when the file is received is incorrect. Any thoughts?